# Oracle SQL. Display data for fixed number of periods from a dynamic start period

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the query I have: I would like to display 6 periods back and 12 periods forward from the value in the PERIOD column:

```
SELECT 
item_id,
min(period),
min(picks_class),
min(vau_class),
min(warehouse_code),
min(stocked)

FROM
(select 
i.warehouse_code,
ih.item_id,
ih.picks_class,
ih.period,
ih.vau_class,
ih.stocked,
substr(i.pareto_set, 6, 6) AS "Policy"

from d_item_history ih
join d_item_snapshot i on ih.item_id=i.id

where ih.picks_class='P2'
and i.supplier_code='DC'
and ih.valid_for_calc='Y'
and ih.vau_class in ('C1', 'C2')
and i.warehouse_code='YAFD'
--    and ih.item_id='1427084842208'

order by ih.period asc
)
group by item_id
;
```

Here is the output of the code: I would like to display the picks class for each one of the ITEM_IDs; 6 periods back from queried period and 12 months forward. 
Please let me know if that is at all possible if/or how. All help is appreciated

[image: Here is what the output looks like right now]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to calculate 6 periods back or 12 periods forward, Are you looking to move by months ? If so, the following code snippet might help you :

```
select to_char(add_months(to_date(period,'YYYYMM'),-6),'YYYYMM') PERIOD_6,
to_char(add_months(to_date(period,'YYYYMM'),12),'YYYYMM')PERIOD_12
 from dual
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Would you suggest using UNION or a JOIN if I need all  18 periods displayed in the same query (6+12). Or something completely different?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was away for a while. Do you want the periods to be displayed in rows or columns ? If within rows, No joins or unions required. If its columns, you can go with UNION ALL if rest of the columns are different.